# Issues in importing SQL Server .bacpac file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to importing a `.bacpac` of Azure DB into a locally running SQL Server 2017 Enterprise edition.

SQL Server is throwing the following error. I wonder if somebody could help. Thank you in advance.

> Could not import package.
>
> Warning SQL72012: The object [xxxx[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWJ9b.png)-insights_Data] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
>
> Warning SQL72012: The object [2pointb-testing-insights_Log] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
>
> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>
> Msg 10343, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   CREATE or ALTER ASSEMBLY for assembly 'GroupConcat' with the SAFE or EXTERNAL_ACCESS option failed because the 'clr strict security' option of sp_configure is set to 1. Microsoft recommends that you sign the assembly with a certificate or asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission. Alternatively, you can trust the assembly using sp_add_trusted_assembly.
>
> Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
>   CREATE ASSEMBLY [GroupConcat]
>       AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
>       FROM 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
>    (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

Comment: The exception message tells you what you need to do.  What are you stuck on?

Comment: `EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options',1;
    GO
    RECONFIGURE;
    GO
    EXEC sp_configure 'clr strict security',0;
    GO`

Comment: This post has more info:https://www.sqlshack.com/impact-clr-strict-security-configuration-setting-sql-server-2017/

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you that helped.

Answer (score 1):

The following script worked for me:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options',1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'clr strict security',0;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```